# Conditional unique number of cells in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, count, range, unique, google-sheets-formula

There are several sheets in the Google spreadsheet with the following content:

[image: Spreadsheet structure]

How to calculate the unique number of cells belonging to AA, AB, and BA?

For AA the answer is: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(IFNA(FILTER(A:A&B:B, A:A="AA")))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

[image: reference image]

Try this: `=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(B:B,A:A,"AA")`

Change the criteria in ("AA") for different results.